# jquery equivalent to javascript piece of the code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this part of the code which works very well on javascript:

```
document.getElementById("firma").onkeypress = function(e) {
return restrictCharacters(this,e,alphaOnly); 
};
```

i'ts part of some script and this part joins it on id="firma"

I'm courious to know what is equivalent if this code in jquery?

it's something like $( "#firma" ).....

Comment: Have you tried anything? See http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: sorry, my mistake, didn't find it from first try..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the jQuery equivalent:

```
$('#firma').on('keypress', function(e) {
    return restrictCharacters(this,e,alphaOnly); 
});
```

`$('#firma')` looks up the element with the ID `firma`. The function `on` is the preferred way to attach event listeners (documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)).

Comment: @dzordz Glad to help! Since this answer helped you, would you mind accepting it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try below

```
$('#firma').on('keypress', function(e) {
    return restrictCharacters(this,e,alphaOnly); 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#firma').keypress(function(e) {
    // your code here
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/